# Populating a second spinner based on what was selected in the first

Tags: android, mysql, database, spinner

Hi I'm working on an Android application. I have a form with 2 spinners (CarMake & CarModel) that allows a user to select a specific car from my mySQL database. I want to load the CarMake spinner with all the entries in the make column of my car database, and from there I want the carModel spinner to only contain models of that make in the database. What would be the easiest way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Assign unique ID's to your CarMake table items, like a primary key. So suppose for Tata you assign ID= 1 Then assign the same ID to all of its model in the CarModel table like a foreign key and then using this ID you can fetch all the models easily. (Hoping you have a different tables for them)

Answer (score 1):

The approach you need is to have a populate method per spinner, so you would have something like this

```
public void populateCarMake()
{...
    // query car make
    // update adapter 1
}
public void populateCarModel( int makeID )
{...
    // query car model where make_id == makeID 
    // update adapter 2
}
```

and in `onitemselect()` of the first spinner call `populateCarModel( makeID );`

Comment: My answer is the code part and @Atul O Holic's is the database part

Answer (score 1):

based on the selection of the spinner item just set the adapter using your new list

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```